# React Bootstrap - Tooltip not showing with img in OverlayTrigger

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, react-bootstrap

I'm kinda new to react and I'm trying to display a tooltip on an image.

```
        <OverlayTrigger placement="right" overlay={(<Tooltip id="hi">Hello, world!</Tooltip>)} triggerType="hover">
            <img alt="" className="char-img rotate_m_5" src="/images/characters/wolf_xs.png"/>
        </OverlayTrigger>
```

But nothing happens when the cursor hovers the image.
I have no errors just nothing happens

Edit : 
I saw in Chrome DevTools that the tooltip appears in the HTML but not in the app, might be a CSS issue.

```
<div id="hi" role="tooltip" class="fade in tooltip top" style="top: 313.75px; left: 448.039px;"><div class="tooltip-arrow" style="left: 50%;"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">Hello, world!</div></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36875266/react-bootstrap-overlaytrigger-and-tooltip-issue

Comment: My issue is not the same as this one and their possibles solution didn't solved it for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add the CSS class "show" to the tooltip

```
<Tooltip id="hi" className="show">Hello World!</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( <
      ReactBootstrap.OverlayTrigger placement = 'top'
      delay = {
        {
          show: 1000
        }
      }
      overlay = { <
        ReactBootstrap.Tooltip id = "tooltip" >
        This is a sample text <
        /ReactBootstrap.Tooltip>
      } >
      <
      img width = "300px"
      src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/07/01/19/48/background-2462431_960_720.jpg" / >
      <
      /ReactBootstrap.OverlayTrigger>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code issue solve

```css
.popover .arrow {
            background: transparent !important;
            z-index: 99;
            width: 0; 
            height: 0; 
            border-left: 7px solid transparent;
            border-right: 7px solid transparent;
            border-top: 7px solid #c7c7c7;
            bottom: -7px;
}
```